# How to add a validation to an input field such that there shouldn't be same values for more than one input field?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm repeating angular material's input fields in my html, hence I'm using `<mat-error>` to show the error message.

I am actually using template driven forms in my code, take a look at the form with input  fields that I have created so far :

```html
<div *ngFor="let distanceVal of distanceArray;let i=index"  layout-gt-xs="row">
   <div flex="30" flex-offset="15">
     <mat-form-field >
       <input matInput placeholder="Distance" type="number" [(ngModel)]="distanceVal.distance" name="distance{{i}}" (change)="distValCheck(distanceVal.distance,i,$event)" required class="number_type_style">
       <mat-error *ngIf="routecheckValue || distanceVal.distance == null">{{ getErrorMessage(distanceVal.distance)}}</mat-error>
       <mat-error *ngIf="routecheckValue">This distance is already added </mat-error>
       <mat-error *ngIf="distanceVal.distance == null">This field is required</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>
   </div>

</div>
```

I'm actually trying to validate  the input field such that if it finds any same value in any of the other input field, mat-error should be shown exactly below the input field where the values are same.

But here my `<mat-error>` is getting executed only when the form is invalid, it is not getting executed with the if condition that I have written by using `*ngIf`

but having the duplicate values from the previous and next input fields does not make a form invalid as it is a built in validator.

Now How should I show a mat-error when I find same values in other input fields

I didn't post the ts file's code as I thought it would not be necessary

Comment: You should implement your own custom validators, please follow the below link. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/advanced-topics/basic-custom-validators/

Comment: Inorder to create a custom validator, I need to create a directive where I write the logic for the validation which will be in a separate ts file.

but input field's values which needs to be checked for duplicate data will be in a separate component. 

how should I write a logic forchecking the data which is in the other component in other component??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate against the sibling controls, you need to put the validator one level higher. Create a wrapper form group around your controls and add the validator there.

Like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ValidatorFn, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

const DuplicateValueValidator: ValidatorFn = (ctrl: FormGroup) => {
  const first = ctrl.get('first').value;
  const second = ctrl.get('second').value;
  const third = ctrl.get('third').value;

  const hasDuplicates = new Set([first, second, third]).size < 3

  return hasDuplicates  ? {
    duplicateValue: 'duplicate values between controls'
  } : null
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      first: ['one'],
      second: ['one'],
      third: ['three']
    }, { validator: DuplicateValueValidator})
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="first" />
    <input formControlName="second" />
    <input formControlName="third" />

  {{ form.hasError('duplicateValue') ? form.getError('duplicateValue') : 'Valid' }}
</form>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjtufw)

Comment: I used template driven form in my code, didn't use reactive form

Comment: Is there any way that  I can validate  with template driven form

Comment: Just follow the steps listed here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms. btw please upvote my answer if you find useful.

Comment: sure, will check it and let u know

Comment: if you cannot figure out how to do it, @me and I'll convert it for you later.

Answer (score 1):

I will post one of my validators that i write:

It's custom Morethan or equal validator.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator} from '@angular/forms';
import {ValidationMessageType} from './validation-message';
import {AbstractValidator} from "./abstract-validator";

@Directive({
    selector: '[moreThanOrEqualNumberValidator][ngModel]',
    providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: 
MoreThanOrEqualNumberValidatorDirective, multi: true}],
    inputs: ['minNumber']
})
export class MoreThanOrEqualNumberValidatorDirective extends AbstractValidator implements Validator, AfterViewInit, OnChanges{

minNumber:number;//input

ngOnChanges(){
    this.updateValidation();
}

ngAfterViewInit(){

}

updateValidation(){
    if(this.control){
        this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}

validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return this.moreThanNumberValidator(control);
}

 moreThanNumberValidator(control:AbstractControl):{[key:string]:any} {
    if (!this.isTouched()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!this.activated) {
        return null;
    }

    if (isNaN(control.value) || control.value < this.minNumber) {
        return {'moreThanOrEqualNumber': {value: null}};
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And i use it in the template driven form like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="alert.operand2" name="operand2" placeholder="قيمة الشرط" moreThanOrEqualNumberValidator [minNumber]="0"/>
```

I hope this will help you to figure your own way to write it :) .

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish that:

1. Create a controller flag
2. In each input field, add a `(keyup)` event

> app.component.ts

```
    hasDuplicates = false;

    validateDuplicity() {
        const setOfDistances = new Set(this.distanceArray.map(distanceVal => distanceVal.distance));
        this.hasDuplicates = setOfDistances.size !== this.distanceArray.length;
    }
```

> app.component.html

```
<input matInput 
       (keyup)="validateDuplicity()" 
       placeholder="Distance" 
       type="number"
       [(ngModel)]="distanceVal.distance" 
       name="distance{{i}}" 
       required
       class="number_type_style">
```

And then, you should use

```
   <mat-error *ngIf="hasDuplicates">This distance is already added</mat-error>
```